# program to take input from line edit and dispaly in line edit

Tags: qlineedit

Hi I'm new to QT i need a program to take input from line edit and using those values perform some operations using those values anfd give output to line edit....
I wrote some code but its not working....
please check it.
Code:

```
enter code here
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
int x,az,el,EL,AZ,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,X,Y,y;
QLineEdit lineEdit
QString az=lineEdit1->text();
QString el=lineEdit2->text();

    AZ=((az*pi)/180);
    EL=((el*pi)/180);

        a=sin(AZ);
        b=cos(AZ);
        c=cos(EL);
        d=cot(EL);
        e=b*d;
        f=-1*e;
        X=atan(f);
        g=c*a;
        Y=asinn(g);
    x=(X*180)/pi;
    y=(Y*180)/pi;

  this->ui->lineEdit3->setText("x");
  this->ui->lineEdit4->setText("y");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to perform some casting. You have retrieved `az` and `el` as `QString` and didn't actually use them.

```
int x,az,el,EL,AZ,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,X,Y,y;
AZ=((az*pi)/180);// undefined int az is used here 
EL=((el*pi)/180);// undefined int el is used here
```

Also `setText ( const QString & )` needs QString as argument so you need to cast `int x` to QString